# A Riley Riddle, Just how you like it.

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I wanted to try my hand at one of these, I apologize if it's not the best.

---

My Prefix is adequate

Not too good, not too bad

It can sometimes describe a time you have had

My infix was not the first

Once traveling in a plastic band

With musical styling far from bland

My suffix starts with one who has created many films

With feline public transit, to swines flying through the air

Certainly no stranger to a retirement scare

From here you'll need slang for an Italian pie

From the first, the second you will deny

When all are combined

The solution you will find

Hopefully you've built up an appetite

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> [OKONOMIYAKI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okonomiyaki).

My Prefix is adequate 
Not too good, not too bad 
It can sometimes describe a time you have had

> It was just OK.

My infix was not the first 
Once traveling in a plastic band 
With musical styling far from bland

> This refers to the collaboration between John and Yoko, the [Plastic ONO Band](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_Ono_Band).

My suffix starts with one who has created many films 
With feline public transit, to swines flying through the air 
Certainly no stranger to a retirement scare

> This is Japanese film director [Hayao MIYAZAKI](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayao_Miyazaki).

From here you'll need slang for an Italian pie

> This would be ‘ZA, the slang for pizza.

From the first, the second you will deny

> Taking ZA out of MIYAZAKI gives MIYAKI.

When all are combined 
The solution you will find 
Hopefully you've built up an appetite

> Putting it together, OK + ONO + MIYAKI = OKONOMIYAKI, a Japanese savoury pancake.

Comment: Indeed you are correct.